# iPhone settings screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to design a screen like settings screen. Like in grouped uitableview I want to place the controls.

Can any one please provide me any application sample or code ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Malleswar

Answer (score 2):

The open source [InAppSettingsKit](http://inappsettingskit.com/) will let you do this easily.

Comment: Hi Brad, Its good. But Is there any direct solution with out open source like directly customizing the table view with controls?

Comment: @malleswar - You wanted source code, so why not take a look at how they achieved this in their framework?  This is exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple's [TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) and their other [sample projects](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+C#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code).

Comment: Hi Alex, I have gone through table view suite, but did not find any useful stuff for settings screen. In sample projects can you please mention the sample which suits for settings screen design.